# SharePoint 2019 - add colour to Web Part table columns and headings

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

I am using SharePoint 2019 and would like to add colour to Web Part table columns and headings. I know how to colour tables if they are made as tables but when I add a Web Part list as a table I cannot seem to edit the headings or columns. Is there a way to colour these aspects of a table?

Idea 1 is what I would like ideally but I would be happy if Idea 2 could be achieved.

Many thanks in advance

Idea 1:

[image]

Idea 2:

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. How does Java enter the picture here?

Comment: Hello, thank you. I added Java as maybe that could provide an idea to a solution. I think HTML is most likely as I have seen that done for column headings before but not something that I know how to manipulate

Comment: Sorry if I insist, but are you sure you don't mean JavaScript instead of Java? Because as far as I know Java is not usually associated with SharePoint.